# checkchanged event is not working with nstudio/nativescript-checkbox plugin

Tags: nativescript

I'm using the plugin tns plugin add @nstudio/nativescript-checkbox.
in document they had given clearly about checkedChange.
But i dont know why it is not working

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=utP80U

```
 <CheckBox:CheckBox checked="{{ checkProp }}" text="{{ myCheckText }}"
                fillColor="{{ myCheckColor }}" id="myCheckbox" checkedChange="{{ checkedChange }}" />


checkedChange : function () {
      console.log("---checkedChange -----");
    },
```

How to use checkedChange event

Comment: The property change events (such as `checkedChange`) should be added once the component is loaded from the code behind file, it's a limitation while using {N} Core.

Comment: @Manoj can you please elaborate your answer or update answer in playground.

Comment: Please refer the [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3971#issuecomment-302021843) for more details.

Comment: @Manoj the link suggests text input change event. but I'm using a plugin and it has the event named checkedChange. So, according to you i need to read checkProp on "onchange" event. so in onchange event what property i need to give instead of on("textChange",....

Comment: @Manoj Sorry i tried something like this https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=utP80U&v=2 and its not working. can you elaborate your answer in an any easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since {N} 3.x property change events are not supported in XML, you must handle them in code behind file.

**XML**

```
<CheckBox:CheckBox checked="{{ checkProp }}" text="{{ myCheckText }}"
                fillColor="{{ myCheckColor }}" id="myCheckbox" loaded="onCheckBoxLoaded" />
```

**JS**

```
function onCheckBoxLoaded(args) {
  args.object.off("loaded");
  args.object.on("checkedChange", homeViewModel.checkedChange);
}
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=utP80U&v=3)

Comment: can you tell me why is this args.object.off("loaded");

Comment: `loaded` event will be triggered again when you navigate back and forth. I'm just trying to avoid redundant event listeners in that case.

Comment: I'm using this in radlistview and it was working fine except. everytime i tap checkbox and console console.log(args.object.page.getViewById("myCheckbox").checked); i'm getting always false. can you tell me why ?

Comment: You are not suppose to use ids when using a component in ListView, why don't you simply check `args.object.checked`.

Comment: k i got it i need to read it by args.object.bindingContext. but one big issue is. when i make it true it will print false. and for false it will print true.  i think its due to delay of time. or something else will it affect performance ?

Comment: It's not the delay, you are accessing the property change event, so you could even do `args.value` for right latest value.

Comment: i didn't get it. i have checkProp value in object args.object.bindingContext and it is {"checkProp": false} for true value. args.value give nothing ...! for radlistview. we need to read it by object.bindingContext only right !!!

Comment: i recreated the issue https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=utP80U&v=6 why it gives true for false and false for true. can you please look at it.